# Has Many Through in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations, has-many-through

Ok so I'll try to make it quick. In my app, a user teaches many courses and a user takes many courses through => "enrollments".

```
User Model:
has_many :courses
has_many :courses, :through => :enrollments, :source => "course_id", :dependent => :destroy

Course Model:
belongs_to :user
has_many :users, :through => :enrollments, :source => "user_id", :dependent => :destroy
```

I set it all up according to standards and the has many through association works great. The problem is that when I am the teacher of the course and I try to delete it, or I try to call :

```
@courses = current_user.courses
```

I get this error:

```
ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughSourceAssociationNotFoundError in CoursesController#destroy
```

I have a feeling that it's because I am calling both a regular has_many/belongs_to relationship even though I already have an existing has_many :through => :enrollments, and something is getting mixed up. I'm not sure how to get around this though. I would ideally like to create a method somewhere that gathers an array of the courses the user is teaching as well, something like current_user.teaching. Pretty lost, any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I would step back a little and start with what is perhaps a more classical hmt approch:

```
User Model:
has_many :enrollments
has_many :courses, :through => :enrollments, :dependent => :destroy
# id, other_fields, e.g. username

Enrollment Model:
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :course
# id, user_id, course_id, other fields, e.g. enrollment_date would be good...

Course Model:
has_many enrollments
has_many :users, :through => :enrollments, :dependent => :destroy
# id, other_fields, e.g. course_name

# `#` lists fields to create through database migrations (not shown).
```

`current_user.courses` might be ok now.

If you get an error make sure it is not about the method not existing for a nil object of course.

Answer (score 0):

Change the declaration for the courses that the user teaches.

`has_many :courses, :as => :taught_courses #or whatever you want`

You may also want to change the declaration in course for clarity:

`belongs_to :user, :as => :teacher`

Comment: I already have those in the models, sorry I should've mentioned that I already included those. Although I think under course it should be has_many :enrollments instead of belongs_to. I think the problem is that I have a regular has_many/belongs_to, and a has many through, so active record is getting tripped up.

Comment: Shouldn't it just be belongs_to :user, and belongs_to :course ?

Comment: Does an enrollment belong to a course, though? I did write it that way first, then changed it. If you want to be able to reference the enrollments of a given course, then it will need to have both belongs_to statements.

Comment: I do, and that's what I did. The real problem is that I need to create an array of the courses the user is teaching, but for some reason that association doesn't work. For instance: @courses = current_user.courses returns the error above.